# Triangle side sum program with input from user (Think Python exercise 5-4-2)

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve Think Python's exercise 5-4-2, which asks to write a program that will prompt the user to input the size of three sticks in order to calculate if they can make up a triangle. The rule is that if any of the three length of the sticks is greater than the sum of the other two, the triangle cannot be made.

Here is my code. The problem is that it always return 'no triangle' (I tried with correct values such as 4, 5 and 3, and with values that should return wrong such as 1,2, and 12), and it always indicates "None" (as if I wasn't using  "return"):

```
    def is_triangle(x,y,z):
        if (x>y+z) or (y>z+x) or (z>x+y):
            print 'no triangle'
        else:
            print 'triangle yes'
        return


    prompt1 = 'Input firt stick length for your triangle please...'
    x = raw_input(prompt1)
    int(x)

    prompt2 = 'Input second stick length for your triangle please...'
    y = raw_input(prompt2)
    int(y)

    prompt3 = 'Input third stick length for your triangle please...'
    z = raw_input(prompt3)
    int(z)


    print is_triangle(x,y,z)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!... Norpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not casting `x` `y` and `z` to integers properly, thus comparing the input **strings** with `>`.

Change

```
 int(x)
```

to

```
 x = int(x)
```

and do the same for `y` and `z`.
The issue here is that you forgot to assign the return value of `int(x)` to the variable `x`, thus `int(x)` has no meaningful effect.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you're not reassigning your `int cast`s back to x, y and z. Thus, they are treated as strings, and in your last comparison, you end up with `(x + y) = 34` (as a string), and the comparison becomes True.

So all the prompt sections should be like this:

```
prompt1 = 'Input firt stick length for your triangle please...'
x = raw_input(prompt1)
x = int(x)
```

Or:

```
prompt1 = 'Input firt stick length for your triangle please...'
x = int(raw_input(prompt1))
```

Answer (score 0):

While structuring the function you can set it out to be the integer.

def is_triangle(a,b,c):

```
if (int(a)>int(b+c)) or (int(b)>int(c+a)) or (int(c)>int(a+b)):

    print("No")

else:

    print("Yes")
```

This is considering the scope limited to your exercise. You can take it to little advanced level by making it dynamic to restrict the user input to be only the integer(in the prompt). Hope you can do that once you move to advance user. Good Luck!